# What are the least common letters to start words?

Tags: alphabet

What letters of the alphabet least commonly appear as the first letter of a word? I'm looking in particular for the 4 least common, but however many you want to give beyond that is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are 5 letters that occur least frequently as first letters of words in English: Z X Q J K (in increasing order - Z is the least common)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Relative_frequencies_of_the_first_letters_of_a_word_in_the_English_language

Comment: Did I seriously not check Wikipedia? I am ashamed. Thanks. :)